# WinForms design-time: How to properly serialize an Image property of my custom UI control

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, serialization

I've made a simple control that draws overlaid transparent images (aligned and in certain order). The images are defined at design-time in VS designer. The whole class looks like this:

```
public class ImageCombinerControl : Control
{
    private List<ImageCombinerItem> _items = new List<ImageCombinerItem>();
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<ImageCombinerItem> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = new List<ImageCombinerItem>(value); } }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items == null) return;
        foreach(var item in Items.Where(i => i.Image != null))
        {
            var x = item.Offset.Width + ((int)item.HAlign * (Width - item.Image.Width)) / 2;
            var y = item.Offset.Height + ((int)item.VAlign * (Height - item.Image.Height)) / 2;
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(item.Image, x, y);
        }
    }        
}

[Serializable]
public class ImageCombinerItem
{        
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public ImageCombinerItemHAlign HAlign { get; set; }
    public ImageCombinerItemVAlign VAlign { get; set; }
    public Size Offset { get; set; }
}

public enum ImageCombinerItemHAlign { Left, Center, Right };
public enum ImageCombinerItemVAlign { Top, Center, Bottom };
```

The first problem is that it doesn't work at runtime, no picture is shown and no exception thrown, in the designer it works normally. 
The second problem is that it embeds images which originate from resources, instead of linking to them. How can I make it work like it works in standard PictureBox.Image?

Comment: I would do this all in code. Using the designer for this kind of code has given me multiple different kind of headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was that the use of `List<T>` caused the designer to use binary serialization in the form's .resx file, which couldn't be properly deserialized afterwards (for some reason). I wrote a custom collection which internally encapsulates `List<T>`, and now it works as it should (now it's serialized into .designer.cs)